# Library to do some 'lambda calculus' in java

Tags: java, lambda-calculus

I am planning to do some basic lambda-expressions manipulation (preferably using typed lambda) in Java.

Is there a library (stable or otherwise) which I use?

UPDATE : To state is more explicitly, I want to manipulate lambda expressions e.g. in a file I parse some lambda expressions and combine some of them to make a new one. Basically, it is more of parsing than functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is [here](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/). Or you can wait for Java 8, 9, 10 (eventually it will be done)?!?!?

Comment: @BrianAgnew Half of my application is already written in java. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Look into functional languages on JVM. This solution more powerful than libs and more useful in future perspective. For that purpose i prefer [Clojure](http://clojure.org/).